Is it possible to remove the line number column/black bar?
That black bar where line numbers usually show, it seems to be the only thing I can't remove. I am trying to create a minimalist word processor along the lines of Notepad++, which I would use except it just self-deleted a file mysteriously.

Did the answer help?

In Settings -> Preferences... -> Margins/Border/Edge you have to disable all off:

line number display
bookmark display
fold margin by setting style to None

